# Bug in the site when using HTTPS

Tags: bug

I'm not quite sure where to report this issue. I encountered a small problem when using SE pages over HTTPS. Assume someone wants to share a link. When clicking on *Share* you'll see `http://…` (without the 's' for SSL/TLS). When you right-click on share you'll get the HTTPS link. So I consider this as a bug.

Comment: Do you have access to the moderator chat? If so, you might mention it there. There are always a few SE devs hanging around. Not sure if there's an official bug tracker or antyhing though; will be curious to find out.

Comment: @SamWhited The meta sites with the bug tag *are* the official bug tracker.

Comment: @MadScientist Makes good sense; thanks.

Comment: This is the right place to report any and all bugs you find.

Comment: Related bug: [Permalink short URLs lose HTTPS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223728/permalink-short-urls-lose-https); before that is fixed, there's not much point in fixing this one.